# Configure message on Location Service iOS system popup

Tags: ios, core-location

My app just been rejected because they found the location service authorization system popup was missing its description message.

But I do have configured the right variable in `info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Nous avons besoin de votre position GPS pour vous situer sur la carte.</string>
```

(it's a french app)

Indeed, here's a screenshot of the popup the first time I launch the app:
[image]

But here is the screenshot the reviewer did take:

[image]

The second popup happen when you turned off the location service globally. To reproduce : accept the permission, go to settings, then turn off the location service, restart the app.

I cannot find a way to configure a message in this second popup. I even wonder if it is possible. Is there a way to do so, is it an error from the reviewer?!

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After trying to contact the Apple team with no constructive answer, I ended up by creating my own screen saying Location Services was recommended to be activated while using the app. Of course, the screen pops up if the app detects disabled location services, by checking `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` method.

With this modification, the app did pass the validation process.